# force registered user as seller

Tags: users

I'm using dokan multivendor, can anyone knows the simple script of forcing all the newly registered to enable the selling mode? when you register as a seller, the selling mode is automatically on, when you register as a customer, the selling mode is off. What I wanted is to have a script of control, for example, if the register register as a contributor or editor, it will automatically make the selling mode "ON".

they have this code:

```
 add_action('gform_post_submission_1', 'marvel_update_dokan_enable_selling', 10, 2);
 function marvel_update_dokan_enable_selling() {
     $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     $current_user_id = $current_user->ID;

     update_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'dokan_enable_selling', 'yes' );

 }
```

but this is for gravity forms

Comment: Could you no hook into `user_register` and then check the role of the user and update their `dokan_enable_selling` accordingly?

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register

Comment: Hi, may I ask how to no hook into user register?

Answer (score 0):

I would hook into `user_register` similarly to how you hooked into `gform_post_submission_1` before. For example:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'awesome_function_name', 10, 1 );
function awesome_function_name( $user_id ) {
    // Conditional logic for testing user role
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'dokan_enable_selling', 'yes' );
}
```

For your conditional logic, if you're trying to make every role do this except customer I typically use the following function which I don't remember where I got so I can't credit them unfortunately.

```
function check_user_role( $role, $user_id = null ) {
    if( is_numeric( $user_id ) ) {
        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    } else {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
    }

    return in_array( $role, (array)$user->roles );
}
```

So your action above would be modified to:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'awesome_function_name', 10, 1 );
function awesome_function_name( $user_id ) {
    if( !check_user_role( 'customer', $user_id ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'dokan_enable_selling', 'yes' );
    }
}
```